# Error writing text on image

Tags: java, android, canvas

I try to write a text on my image:

```
private Bitmap drawText() {
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
             R.drawable.test); 

    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    paint.setTextSize(5);
    canvas.drawText("Some Text here", 5, 5, paint);

    Bitmap resBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(canvas.getWidth(),
            canvas.getHeight(), Config.RGB_565);
    canvas.setBitmap(resBitmap);
    return resBitmap;

}
```

the result is a completely black image. What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: I don't think so. That's just how you set up the text color

Comment: You are returning a new `Bitmap`, not a `Bitmap` on which text is drawn. so return `bitmap` after `canvas.drawText(...)`. You don't need `resBitmap`...

Comment: @user3367856 try like as jon skeet said its working..

Answer (score 3):

**Disclaimer: I'm not an Android developer. I've never written code like this. It's just my interpretation of the documentation...**

I suspect you *actually* want to set the bitmap to draw onto much earlier, and then draw the other bitmap *into* the canvas. So something like:

```
private Bitmap drawText() {
    // Load the existing image to get some dimensions
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
        R.drawable.test); 

    // Create a result bitmap and a canvas which draws onto it
    Bitmap resBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap.getWidth(),
        bitmap.getHeight(), Config.RGB_565);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(resBitmap);

    // Draw the existing image into the canvas
    canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0f, 0f, null);

    // Draw text on top
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    paint.setTextSize(5);
    canvas.drawText("Some Text here", 5, 5, paint);

    return resBitmap;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

u set background of canvas from this

```
  paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
```

and by `default text color is also black` i.e u can see only that black screen

try from this

```
    paint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
```

Comment: I tried commenting out this line and I tried changing it to green. Same problem..

Comment: and also try to change text color with black once

Answer (score 0):

change the Background color and foreground color of the canvas.

```
Paint paint = new Paint();
paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
paint.setStyle(Style.FILL);
canvas.drawPaint(paint);

paint.setColor(android.R.color.black);
paint.setTextSize(20);
canvas.drawText("Some Text", 10, 25, paint);
```

ensure that the color of the text must be different from the background color